cascode NMOS (virtuoso)

I have run across a problem.
When I was trying to design a cascode amplifier that was gain>=10V
I have succeeded to make it.
The rout in gm/Id method is 1.58M ohms.
When I  typed the width and length at the first picture,
it turned up that the rout is 84k ohms.
Why there is a huge difference for rout between cascode simulation and gm/Id method.
Thanks for helping.
Picture Reference: My own screenshot from cadence virtuoso (all)

M0



M1


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@jsdklfsldn Maybe showing how you got your gm/id curves will help others in the community answer your question. Like what the testbench looks like, how you set up the simulation, and what the x- and y-axes represent.

@GeorgeGuo For M1, the current should flow 60uA. For M0, the gain should be above 10V/V, so I set gm of M0 as 1mA/V. I left the margin for 20%, so gm of M0 is 1.2mA/V.
The current is 60uA. Thus, gm/id is 20. Then I take 20 to correspond to upper left, we get the value of id/w equaling to 0.5643. I take 14.01 to correspond to the lower right, we can get vgs equal to 406.6mV.

This may be because the Vds of M0 in the cascode configuration is different from that in your characterisation configuration (the one used for getting the gm/id curves). I did a quick test on a 180nm process and found the Vds actually has a huge impact on rout, even if the transistor is in saturation region. Maybe the Vds in your testbench for characterisation is much larger than 686mV, hence it has a much larger rout.
Maybe fix the Vds in your characterisation testbench to 686mV and then sweep the Vg to see how the rout changes.

https://imgur.com/a/5KlxlOY

Thanks for help. I notice that the vds I have swept is not the same as what I got for one mosfet simulation. I have set that the drain of M1 should be 500mV. This might be the reason that does not match rout of the m1 in cascode. But how come that there is huge difference between two different simulation?

@jsdklfsldn rout is inversely proportional to the slope in the Ids-Vds plot. Maybe the curve is not so straight even in the saturated region. I don't know the reason behind this, maybe some device physicists can explain this. The lesson we have learned as analogue circuit designers is that the assumptions made in textbooks may be different from the process/tech we are using.

@jsdklfsldn why don't you do it the other way around: Find the gm/Id of your transistors in the circuit and in your TB char. results whether you can find back the same rout value?

@Designalog yep I tried your way, and I got almost the same value as what I posted gm/id curve in the article.

The way you connect a transistor in a circuit does not change its intrinsic properties. No matter whether your MOSFET is used stand-alone or in a cascode, its output resistance will be around 80k. This resistance, however, is not necessarily the total output resistance of the overall circuit.
The cascode serves to lessen the impact of the individual MOSFET's output resistance on the circuit's overall properties. Essentially, it keeps the drain-source voltage of the lower FET nearly constant, so that the current flowing through it does not vary much despite its low output resistance.
So in short, while each individual MOSFET might still have terrible electrical properties, the complete cascode circuit is much better.
In particular, the output resistance of the lower FET (80k) gets multiplied by the intrinsic gain of the upper FET (66), which in your case comes out to be around 5 MOhms. The (smaller) discrepancy compared to the simulated value of 1.6 MOhm can be explained by the fact that the upper FET's bulk is not connected to its source, which causes a degradation in gain and leakage current.

I think the OPs issue is that his characterization TB for the same transistor size gives a very different rout compared to using this transistor in the cascode simulation. Not the rout of the whole amplifier (AFAIU).The OP is not clear about how he characterized the transistor, so if the Idrain/Vgs in his char. TB is different from his cascode simulation differences are bound to happen.

@Designalog I might've misunderstood the question then - let's see what OP says about the answer. Maybe it clears things up for them, maybe not.

@JonathanS. That's the situation said by designalog I am struggling right now.
